# How can I create a new instance of a form class and then open it as a acDialog box (pausing other code)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

## Problem

I have a complex search form that I need to open several times (at the same time) to allow users to do multiple searches at the same time. I have found the ability to open an instance of the form (as it is a class) using:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Array to hold Form Instances
Private MyFormCollection(1 To 4) As Form_frmTest

Private Sub cmd_CloneMe_Click()
    Dim intCounter As Integer

    For intCounter = 1 To 4
        Set MyFormCollection(intCounter) = New Form_frmTest
        MyFormCollection(intCounter).Caption = "Form #" & intCounter
        MyFormCollection(intCounter).Visible = True
    Next intCounter

    Forms!frmTest.SetFocus
End Sub
```

*This is an example to open multiple instances of a form and not what I will use for the final code as I will only need to open one instant per click BUT will likely have other already open!*

BUT I can't work out a way to one of those duplicates as an acDialog (so calling function pauses until you hide or close the new dialog form). Here is the way I would normally open a normal form (not a copy):

```
Call DoCmd.OpenForm("SomeForm", acNormal, , , , acDialog)
```

---

## Question

**How can I open a new instance of a form as an Dialog box (so calling function pauses until new form is closed or hidden)?**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the form's modal property to true?

Comment: Yer but that just stops the user clicking on any other forms it doesn't stop the calling code running until the new form is closed/hidden like dialog does. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to check if a form is visible:

```
Private Function IsVisible(intObjType As Integer, strObjName As String) As Boolean
    Dim intObjState As Integer
    intObjState = SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, intObjType, strObjName)
    IsVisible = intObjState And acObjStateOpen
End Function
```

If yes, do nothing but wait:

```
Do While IsVisible(acForm, "frmInfo")
    DoEvents
Loop
```

==================

Ok, another idea: you either have the choice of opening a dialog modal and stop the code in the calling function, or live with more dialogs and have the calling function running.

I think the only way of solving this is a counter of the dialogs open, and refusing to do anything in the calling function when the count is still > 0.

Comment: Yer I already have a this option working but really don't like the constant look running. There could be 4-5 open at the same time. PC's will cry! ;)

Comment: Oh just realised this one requires the forms name.. for forms that have several instances this won't work. :(

Comment: This is pretty much what I did in the end. Thanks. Your version of the "IsVisible()" (as mentioned earlier) doesn't quite work but the one here does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354927/ and using that and the rest of your idea I got what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a public function in your called form and until that function returns (by closing the form) the calling method is blocked. In the example below clicking a "Done" button might set the return

```
Option Explicit
Private m_dlgResult As VbMsgBoxResult

Public Function ShowDialog() As VbMsgBoxResult

    m_dlgResult = vbCancel
    Me.Show vbModal
    ShowDialog = m_dlgResult

End Function

Private Sub Done_Click()

    m_dlgResult = vbOK
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but again Modal isn't the same as dialog. Model just stops the user from interacting with other forms while that form is open. Dialog pauses the calling functions code until you close it.

Comment: @Zasurus Sorry I misunderstood, still pretty easy - see the revised answer

Comment: @Zasurus In VB6 `Show`ing with the vbModal flag does exactly what you stated, it blocks (pauses) the code that called Show until the form is dismissed.

Comment: @tcarvin: Yer have found that (from all the reading I have done on this in the last 8 hours! ;)) but I am working in Access 2010 so VBA no good to me :( Thanks though.

Comment: @Beaner: Thanks again. Already tried this method but to do this I would need the called form to know that function exists and even the form it was called from (which it doesn't as it is opened from lots of other forms as well). I did look into passing it the forms name and functions name and using Eval() or CallByName() to run it but that started getting really messy. :(